# Wrap a set of paragraphs with no markup and random <br> in p tags

Tags: javascript

I'm working on themes for a legacy API that spits out less than wonderful / if not markup-less / markup. I've been able to wrestle most of it back into shape with `wrap()` and other methods, but for some reason this one is stumping me. Do I really need to get out the for loops for something like this - or is there a cheap and dirty way to get these paragraphs into `<p`> paragraphs?

```
<div class="bio">
    "Some Ember is the new solo project of Man/Miracle's Dylan Travis. "Era of Wind" is only the second song he's released, it is icy and desolate. It's a little bit Lovecraft (From fingertip to dilated eye/ it closes grip on vibrated flesh, Travis sings) and a little bit Fever Ray, propelled by haunted, droning bass. I keep thinking about this lonely guy in a lake, like a 19th century convict rowing through fog, making his great escape from an island prison and sinking halfway to shore. What happens to that guy? What if he had a Moog to play on the way down? " --The Fader
    <br>
    <br>
    "Like some kind of abridged soundtrack to Bergman's Persona pared down to its abstract purity, this ten minute mood piece charts a psychic journey through dissolution and restructure, opening with a searing purge of the sonic palate, only to find itself wading through the aftermath's fog of disarray. Taking cues from the likes of Mazzy Star, Happy New Year and Grouper, the San Francisco duo immerse themselves in a narcotic mixture of sensuality and obliqueness, mostly leaving meaning and catharsis to hover just out of reach while an ominous air of gloom takes hold." --Sonic Masala
</div>
```

Feels like trying to get these in shape might not be worth it. Thoughts?

Comment: If you can count on the `<br>` tags, you could use them to `.split()` the string and then `.join()` it back together with paragraph tags. Not exactly pretty, but it should work.

Comment: I thought about that, but I can't really count on any breaks    : /

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can achieve this using the  childNodes in DOM .

```js
$("#btnConvert").on("click",function(){
 var text = $("#text");
     result = $("<div>").html(text.val()).children().contents().filter(function() {
  return this.nodeType == 3 && this.data.trim() != "";
}).map(function(){ return "<p>"+this.data+"</p>"}).get().join("");
    text.val(result);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>value</p>
<textarea name="text" id="text" cols="30" rows="10">
    <div class="bio">
    "Some Ember is the new solo project of Man/Miracle's Dylan Travis. "Era of Wind" is only the second song he's released, it is icy and desolate. It's a little bit Lovecraft (From fingertip to dilated eye/ it closes grip on vibrated flesh, Travis sings) and a little bit Fever Ray, propelled by haunted, droning bass. I keep thinking about this lonely guy in a lake, like a 19th century convict rowing through fog, making his great escape from an island prison and sinking halfway to shore. What happens to that guy? What if he had a Moog to play on the way down? " --The Fader
    <br>
    <br>
    "Like some kind of abridged soundtrack to Bergman's Persona pared down to its abstract purity, this ten minute mood piece charts a psychic journey through dissolution and restructure, opening with a searing purge of the sonic palate, only to find itself wading through the aftermath's fog of disarray. Taking cues from the likes of Mazzy Star, Happy New Year and Grouper, the San Francisco duo immerse themselves in a narcotic mixture of sensuality and obliqueness, mostly leaving meaning and catharsis to hover just out of reach while an ominous air of gloom takes hold." --Sonic Masala
</div>
</textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" id="btnConvert" name="btnConvert" value="Convert">
```

Comment: Looks like a promising approach. I haven't been able to spend much time using this, but it seemed to rely on that outer div, which I can't really place there. My html is as outlined. Trying to munge it out...

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [Regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) if you're going to be doing a lot of this.  You get much more control over your text and the code is short.

I called [`.match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) on the innerHTML and using this regex string `/".+/g`.  It finds all text from the left-most quote until a newline.

```
text.match(/".+/g);
```

Here's how the match parses out.
https://regex101.com/r/mP7pU9/1

This is how it looks in jQuery.
http://jsfiddle.net/jg7cxpy4/2/